# How to debug android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException

Tags: android

We're seeing quite a few of these exceptions in our crash logging tool.

The stacktrace contains only android functions:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@4150fa88 is not valid; is your activity running?
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:646)
   at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2964)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:156)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1340)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

How would you proceed with finding the cause of this?
We can't get more information than this I'm afraid.

My guess is we're trying to show a popup or something after the activity has died.

Comment: Could you please share how you fixed it ? I am having similar crash reports.

Comment: We still haven't solved this I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually linked to keeping references to a dead Context or starting a Dialog with the wrong Context.